# Json.Net Serialized object losing its Id value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Json.Net to serialize and deserialize an object.

I am experiencing an issue where the deserialized object recordPosted has zero as its Id.

Whereas the Serialized record will contain an Id of 180

```
JsonSerializerSettings jsSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
jsSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;

var recordAsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recordToUpdate, 
                                Formatting.None, jsSettings);
//recordAsJson = {"Id":180,....


 var recordPosted = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<record>(recordAsJson);
 //recordPosted = Id : 0
```

How would I resolve this?

***Edit***

```
public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
```

Comment: Can we see how `record.Id` is declared please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Json.NET doesn't set private property setters by default. Either make the setter public or place a [JsonProperty] attribute on the property.

Comment: I've just come across this because (v 6.0) it wasn't setting private properties if they were `int` but was if they were `string`s.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show `record`, but I would wager that you have something like:

```
private int id;
public int Id { get { return id; } }
```

there isn't much that the serializer can do here to set `Id`, so... it doesn't. Note: some serializers (`XmlSerializer`, for example) will also refuse to *serialize* such, but JSON serializers tend to be more forgiving, since it is pretty common to use *only* the serialize, to return data from a web-server to a javascript client, including from anonymous types (which are immutable in C#).

You could *try* having a private `set`:

```
private int id;
public int Id { get { return id; } private set { id = value; } }
```

(or alternatively)

```
public int Id { get; private set; }
```

If that still doesn't work - it may have to be fully public:

```
private int id;
public int Id { get { return id; } set { id = value; } }
```

(or alternatively)

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi Marc, I have added the declaration. This an object that is saved via nHibernate.

Comment: @Nicholas then I wasn't a million miles out... it looks like JSON.Net doesn't like the `private`. If nHibernate can't be made to add a public `set`, I would recommend using a separate DTO for serialization purposes.

Comment: Cheers, Marc I'll look into the nHibernate public/private set first.

Comment: nHibernate to public set does not seem possible - I'll go for a separate DTO for serialization but it seems a bit kludgy...?

Comment: sorry Marc but I'll have to change my accept answer considering the reply from James himself.

Comment: @Nicholas no problem; glad to see the other answer